# Not able to load the data into Apache Hadoop

Tags: hadoop3

We are using 2 nodes and in one node we have installed all the services (NN, DN, RM, NM, Hive) and from other node we are trying to run the jobs to load the data.

Error:

> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: File /user/mapred/huawei/mhr_sms_mt_bill_home_routed/date_hour=2023-11-21-07/mt_bill_home_routed_mhrcn-smsc-02_20231121073956Z_CSV_SM_mt_bill_home_routed.csv.date_hour=2023-11-21-07.lzo could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation

how to fix this?

We are using Apache Hadoop 3.3.6 and OS: RHEL 8.6

I tried to check the Rep factor set in hdfs-site, core-site, block size.
checked the datanode, nameode services
Checked the space utilization.

Comment: Any help or suggestions from anyone

Comment: Any suggestions or comments from anyone?